# Jmeter passing value from one response to another request

Tags: arrays, parsing, jmeter

I am trying to parse the array value from the response of one request and pass it to another request.From one api I get the response as :
{"id":95,"email":"Test_rider_00002@popup.com","firstname":"test","lastname":"rider","phoneNumber":"9999990002","phoneNumberVerified":true,"emailVerified":true,"address":{"address":"2400 Perimeter Rd, Auburn, WA 98001, USA","zipCode":"98001"},"dateOfBirth":"2000-10-05","gender":"UNKNOWN","fullName":"test rider","enabled":true,"isDriver":false,"avatars":[{"id":131,"type":"RIDER","active":true}]}

I need to use the id from the avatars array in the next request .But ,I am unable to do so using the pre and post processors .

I have tried using the JSON Extractor,JSR223 Processor and RegEx extractor but to no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use Reg. expression extractor with the below expression:

"avatars":[{"id":(.+?),

Answer (score 0):

I believe [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) can do the trick for you, the relevant [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#getting-started) query would be something like:

```
$.avatars.*.id
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [How to Use the JSON Extractor For Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor)